# Cambio de monedas, no me devuelve cantidad exacta

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al realizar un programa, pido al usuario que me de dos valores, el primero un precio y el segundo un ingreso, quiero sacar el cambio pero no me lo hace exacto.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Indica el precio: ");
        double pre = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Indica la cantidad que has ingresado: ");
        double ing = sc.nextDouble();

        double devolver;
        devolver = ing - pre;
        System.out.print("Su cambio: ");
        while (devolver != 0) {
            if (devolver >= 2) {
                System.out.println("Monedas de 2 euros: " + devolver);
                devolver= devolver-2;
            }
            if (devolver >= 1) {
                System.out.println("Monedas de 1 euro: " + devolver);
                devolver= devolver-1;
            }
            if (devolver >= 0.5) {
                System.out.println("Monedas de 50 centimos: " + devolver);
                devolver= devolver-0.5;
            }
            if (devolver >= 0.2) {
                System.out.println("Monedas de 20 centimos " + devolver);
                devolver= devolver-0.2;
            if (devolver >= 0.1) {
                System.out.println("Monedas de 10 centimos: " + devolver);
                devolver= devolver-0.1;
            }
            if (devolver >= 0.05) {
                System.out.println("Monedas de 5 centimos: " + devolver);
                devolver= devolver-0.05;
            }
```

En la salida del system.print me da:

```
Indica el precio: 0,65
Indica la cantidad que has ingresado: 1
Su cambio: Monedas de 20 centimos 0.35
Monedas de 10 centimos: 0.14999999999999997
```

No entiendo la salida de dicho código o si me he saltado algo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ese problema se debe a que los ordenadores trabajan en binario y a la hora de trabajar con variables de tipo float o double cometen errores de precisión al trabajar con valores que no pueden representar.
si queremos representar 1/3, el resultado es 0.3333333333333… y así hasta el infinito. No podemos dar un valor exacto a esa operación. Y a los ordenadores les pasa exactamente lo mismo, si quieren representar por ejemplo 1/100, el resultado sería 1100110011001100110011001100110011… y así hasta el infinito.

Podrias la proxima usar BigDecimal pero tambien puedes cambiar tu codigo a esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Indica el precio: ");
    double pre = Double.parseDouble(sc.readLine());
    pre = pre * 100;
    int precio = (int) pre;

    System.out.print("Indica la cantidad que has ingresado: ");
    double ing = Double.parseDouble(sc.readLine());
    ing = ing * 100;
    int ingreso = (int) ing;

    int devolver;
    int resto = ingreso % 5;
    if (resto != 0)
        System.out.println(ingreso + " No es múltiplo de " + 5);
    else {
        if (ingreso < precio) {
            System.out.println("Dinero insuficiente...");
        } else {
            devolver = ingreso - precio;
            System.out.print("Su cambio: ");
            while (devolver != 0) {
                if (devolver >= 200) {
                    System.out.println("Monedas de 2 euros: " + devolver / 200);
                    devolver %= 200;
                }
                if (devolver >= 100) {
                    System.out.println("Monedas de 1 euro: " + devolver / 100);
                    devolver %= 100;
                }
                if (devolver >= 50) {
                    System.out.println("Monedas de 50 centimos: " + devolver / 50);
                    devolver %= 50;
                }
                if (devolver >= 20) {
                    System.out.println("Monedas de 20 centimos " + devolver / 20);
                    devolver %= 20;
                }
                if (devolver >= 10) {
                    System.out.println("Monedas de 10 centimos: " + devolver / 10);
                    devolver %= 10;
                }
                if (devolver >= 5) {
                    System.out.println("Monedas de 5 centimos: " + devolver / 5);
                    devolver %= 5;
                }
            }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Entonces debo cambiar todo el codigo y usar esa variable de BigDecimal para comparar?

Comment: Si, me funciona de esa manera. Gracias.